# How to count comaprisons and swaps in Quicksort in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I have a simple method to sort an array of int with Quicksort. I dont know how to properly count the number of swaps and comparisons, since the algorithm is recursive:

```
public void quicksort(int tablica[], int x, int y) {
    int i,j,v,temp;
    i=x;
    j=y;
    int swaps=0;
    int comparisons=0;
    v=tablica[(x+y) / 2];
    while (i<=j)
    {
        while (tablica [i] <v)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (tablica [j] >v)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i<=j){
            temp = tablica [i];
            tablica [i]=tablica[j];
            tablica [j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
            swaps++;
        }
        comparisons++;
    }
    if (x<j)
        quicksort(tablica,x,j);
    if (i<y)
        quicksort(tablica,i,y);
    System.out.println("Comparisons: " + comparisons);
    System.out.println("Swaps: " + swaps);
}
```

Running it with small (10 ints) array returns this:

```
Comparisons: 1
Swaps: 1
Comparisons: 1
Swaps: 1
Comparisons: 2
Swaps: 2
Comparisons: 1
Swaps: 1
Comparisons: 1
Swaps: 1
Comparisons: 1
Swaps: 1
Comparisons: 2
Swaps: 1
Comparisons: 4
Swaps: 4
```

How to do it properly?

Comment: You can define the variables as fields instead', for example.

Answer (score 1):

Define a class variable instead and on each run of the quick sort method update the class variable.

Example

```
public class example {
  private int swaps=0;
  private int comparisons=0;

  public void quicksort(int tablica[], int x, int y) {
    int i,j,v,temp;
    i=x;
    j=y;

    v=tablica[(x+y) / 2];
    while (i<=j)
    {
        while (tablica [i] <v)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (tablica [j] >v)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i<=j){
            temp = tablica [i];
            tablica [i]=tablica[j];
            tablica [j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
            swaps++;
        }
        comparisons++;
    }
    if (x<j)
        quicksort(tablica,x,j);
    if (i<y)
        quicksort(tablica,i,y);
    System.out.println("Comparisons: " + comparisons);
    System.out.println("Swaps: " + swaps);
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the proper (I think) results, but "Comparisons: 21
Swaps: 18" still is printed multiple times

Comment: Move the print statements to after you call the quick sort method.

Comment: Just move the last two lines of printing outside of the quicksort method and into `main` (right after you call quicksort) and you'll get one print with the final results. @filiard

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AtomicInteger to pass your counters around by reference. As opposed to using a class variable, this approach is thread safe and will allow you to perform multiple sorts at the same time while keeping your stats separate.

Redefine your method signature:

```
public void quicksort(int tablica[], int x, int y, AtomicInteger comparisons, AtomicInteger swaps) {
```

... and increment the value each time you perform a swap or comparison. Change this:

```
swaps++;
```

... to this:

```
swaps.incrementAndGet();
```

... and change this:

```
comparisons++;
```

... to this:

```
comparisons.incrementAndGet();
```

Lastly, update your recursion calls:

```
if (x<j)
    quicksort(tablica,x,j, comparisons, swaps);
if (i<y)
    quicksort(tablica,i,y, comparisons, swaps);
```

**Edit:** When you want to call the quicksort:

```
AtomicInteger comparisonCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger swapCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
quicksort(tablica, x, y, comparisonCounter, swapCounter);

// now you can print out the total number of swaps and comparisons
// using swapCounter.get() and comparisonCounter.get()
```

Comment: How to call this method now, with two AtomicIntegers? It used to be like this:
      quicksort (tablica, 0, tablica.length-1, );
but now i have to add AtomicIntegers, which I dont have.

Comment: Edited to demonstrate calling the quicksort.